# Django queryset: order_by ForeignKey boolean attribute

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to order a queryset so that:

- the first elements of the queryset are those which have a ForeignKey boolean attribute (`first`) set to True, and amongst them, they are ordered by creation date
- the following elements are those having ForeignKey `first` attribute set to False, and again amongst them, they are ordered by creation date

Here is an example of the models:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    first = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The queryset looks like:

```py
queryset = B.objects.all().order_by("-a__first", "-created")
```

This snipper, however, is not doing the work.

A solution that I'm thinking of is to use two different databases call (one filtering for a__first=True and the other filtering for a__first=False), and then sum up the querysets results. But I would like to understand if there is a better and cleaner way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following conditional query, it might possibly work

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

B.objects.annotate(
    first_true=Case(
        When(a__first=True, then=('created')),
        default=None
    ),
    first_false=Case(
        When(a__first=False, then=('created')),
        default=None
    )
).order_by(
    '-first_true',
    '-first_false',
)
```

Comment: Umm. elements should be ordered by "first" first, and by "created" then. You are using Cases and assigning `created` when `first` is True. This does not make much sense?

Comment: `first_true` has a value only when `first` is True, so those get priority, and then by date second since the value is the date. Then likewise for when first is False. Did you try it? If it doesn't work I'll delete the answer, just had this idea.